# Convert .net date to Java date

Tags: java, android, .net, parsing

In my code, I'm receiving a date formatted: `/Date(-82135555200000-0800)/`

How can I parse it in Java to become a Java date?

Comment: Can you send the date in milliseconds instead of this format?

Comment: No, I can't, I only get this, someone else is responsable for sending data, and he is sending this

Comment: What is that format? What date is this supposed to be?

Comment: If you know the format at least you can tell it to java or implement a converter

Comment: This is .net date with sql, I need a java date, I have found solutions and converters, but the problem parsing this date is the second hypen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `string` `/Date(-82135555200000-0800)/`

use this line of code to remove non-number element from the `String`

```
String tempDate = data.getDate().replaceAll("\\D+", "");
```

what you actually be interested in should be `8213555520000` . you would need first 15 digits to get the date from it as the given time is in milliseconds, you can do whatever you want with it. 
Many languages follow this convention so  dealing with date becomes easy

```
Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(""+tempDate));
```

Or as following

```
String dateAsText = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        .format(new Date(821355552*10000L));
```